# Events or Handlers? Invoking methods from a thread

Tags: java, android, events, handler

Consider a simple Android application: there are two TabActivities and a thread in the background getting integer values from a server. If the number is even, it must be displayed in the first tab otherwise in the second. Obviously I will be doing something more complicated, but this is the basic pattern. How do I go about doing this? I have been scratching my head for about a day now and here are things I have come across:

1. Use of EventHandlers. The two TabActivities register for listening for my_events and when a value is received by the thread, it 'throws my_event' and then specific methods in both these activites are called and the value is passed.
2. The use of Handlers.

I have not used both of these concepts before and I would like to know which might be the better/correct route to take. Further, any more tips along the chosen route will be appreciated. Also, should this thread be run from a service class?

Answer (score 0):

When you create your thread just pass the objects of your tabs into it, then in your execution you can easily put the text you want into tabs.

Comment: Thanks but the function I intend to do upon receiving an event from the thread is lot more complex and so I do not intend to do it in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you want to look at using an AysncTask. If you do this you want to insert the values into the appropriate tab in the onProgressUpdate() method. Since the arguments passed to this method may not actually be able to represent the incoming data sufficiently you'll just want to put the new data somewhere that it can be accessed from the onProgressUpdate() method, probably in a member variable. Keep in mind that access to this member variable probably needs to be synchronized because code in onProgressUpdate is running on the application's main thread, while code in doInBackground is running on a background thread so code in these methods will be running concurrently.

AsyncTask uses Handlers transparently for you, but you could use raw Handlers if you wanted. The basic things you need to keep in mind are

- You can/should only update the UI from the main application thread
- Code in a Handler will *always* run on the Thread that created the Handler
- Handlers must be created on a Thread that has a Looper (the main Thread has a Looper)
- Be careful if creating the Handler as an anonymous inner class or handing it a reference to a Context since this creates the potential for a memory leak

Possibly the Thread should be invoked by a Service, but if the Thread only needs to exist when there is a UI for it to update there may be little point to this.

Comment: thanks.. I finally ended up building my own event handlers and looks like they are working fine..